# Trino - Catalog only supports writes using autocommit: <catalog_name> - Trino dbapi

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds, trino

While I try to connect postgres RDS Database using Trino server, using catalog.

I getting this Error:

```
trino.exceptions.TrinoUserError: TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=AUTOCOMMIT_WRITE_CONFLICT, message="Catalog only supports writes using autocommit: <catalog_name>", query_id=20240103_105150_00001_w6b9p)
```

here is my python code:

```
from trino.dbapi import connect
from trino.auth import BasicAuthentication
from trino.transaction import IsolationLevel

with connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=8080,
        user="username",
        auth=BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
        http_scheme="https",
        isolation_level=IsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE,
        verify=False,
        catalog="my_catalog_name"
) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (4, 5, 6)')
```

here is my catalog:

```
connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/db_name?ssl=true
connection-user=postgres
connection-password=password
```

I expect to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the catalog you are using ("my_catalog_name") only supports writes using autocommit. You need to modify your Python code to use autocommit when executing the SQL statement.

```
from trino.dbapi import connect
from trino.auth import BasicAuthentication

# Use the `isolation_level` parameter to set autocommit
with connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=8080,
        user="username",
        auth=BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
        http_scheme="https",
        isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT",  # Set to AUTOCOMMIT for autocommit mode
        verify=False,
        catalog="my_catalog_name"
) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (4, 5, 6)')
```

Comment: I want to run like a Transactions query, if any error I want to rollback the data.


for example:

If I run two insert queries, I want to execute the first query, and if it is successful, 
Proceed to the second query. However, if I encounter any error in the second query, 
I want to rollback the changes made by the first query as well.